# Issues passing data up React tree to change DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-redux, bootstrap-4

** This may be a simple answer, I'm new to React, thank you for any help ! **

### Back story

I have a modal(bootstrap4) hidden inside the main `app` with a form inside that, when it rendered, the form is filled out based on the information from the selected recipe (more on that later.)

The recipes are stored locally and with `this.state.currentRecipe` I know which recipe is being selected (it is used as the index and is set to 0 by default.)

So, using `this.state.currentRecipe` as the index the first render naturally puts in the first recipe's information.

I attempted to solve this by making a function and passing it down the child components. The recipe-card has all the information and the edit button inside of it. So when the recipe-cards are all rendered by `.map()` I pass in their index and the function that was passed down in order to change the state of `this.state.currentRecipe` and re-render the DOM with the form having the new information.

### What's wrong

Everything loads however, when I click the edit button the modal pops up with the first recipe *always*. It will even change `this.state.currentRecipe` but the DOM doesn't re-render with the proper recipe's information.

#### How do I get the form's information to update based on which recipe-card I'm in when I click the 'Edit' button?(there is a button in each card).

**(and even if it did, would it just hide the modal again?)**

Here is the link to the component folder of the repo https://github.com/JeremyWeisener/React-Recipe-box/tree/master/src/components

in case the code below isn't enough information

## Here is the inside of the 4 main files I believe matter (cleaned up a bit and put here to make life easier)

## app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import RecipeCard from './recipe-card';
import RecipeBook from './recipe-book';
import AddRecipe from './add-recipe';
import RecipeEditer from './edit-recipe';

export default class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            currentRecipe: 0,
            recipes: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cookBook')),
            updateKey: 0,
            counter: 0
        }
    }

    changeRecipe = (arg) => {

        this.setState({currentRecipe:arg});

    }


  render() {

    return (

    <div>
        <div>
          <RecipeBook changeRecipe={this.changeRecipe.bind(this)} recipes={this.state.recipes} />         

        </div>

        <div id="popUps">
            <AddRecipe />
            <RecipeEditer index={this.state.currentRecipe} forglory={this.state} />
        </div>

        <div id="editPopup">

        </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

## recipe-book.js

```
import React from 'react';
import RecipeCard from './recipe-card';

const RecipeBook = (props) => {

        var changeRecipe = props.changeRecipe;

        console.log(props);

        const DisplayRecipes = props.recipes.map((recipe, index) => {

            return <RecipeCard index={index} key={index+1} recipe={recipe} changeRecipe={changeRecipe.bind(this)} />

        })



    return (

        <div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

            {DisplayRecipes}

                  <div>
                    <button className="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addRecipe"> Add Recipe </button>
                  </div>

        </div>
    );

}

export default RecipeBook;
```

## recipe-card.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Ingredients from './recipe-ingredients';
import Steps from './recipe-steps';
import RecipeEditer from './edit-recipe';

const RecipeCard = (props) => {

    const changeRecipe = props.changeRecipe;

    return (    
        <div>
        {/*Card Start*/}
        <div className="recipe card">
            {/*Header*/}
            <div className="card-header" role="tab" id={`heading${props.index}`}>
              <h5 className="mb-0">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href={`#collapse${props.index}`} aria-expanded="true" aria-controls={`collapse${props.index}`}>
                {props.recipe.title}
                </a>
              </h5>
            </div>
            {/*End Header*/}

            {/*Collapse Div*/}
                <div id={`collapse${props.index}`} className="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby={`heading${props.index}`}>
                {/*Card IMG*/}
                <img className="card-img-top" src="./img/Fried Chik'n-edit1.jpg" />
                {/*Card Block*/}
                <div className="card-block">
                    <p className="card-text">

                    </p>
                        {/* Ingredients */}
                    <h3>Ingredients</h3>
                    <Ingredients parts={props.recipe.ingredients} />
                        {/* Steps */}
                    <h3>Steps</h3>
                    <Steps levels={props.recipe.steps} />

                    <a href="#" className="btn btn-primary">Print Recipe</a>

                    {/*Edit Button is here*/}
                    <button onClick={() => {changeRecipe(props.index)}} className="btn btn-success" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editRecipe"> Edit Recipe </button>
                    {/*Edit Button is here*/}

                    <a href="#" className="btn btn-danger">Delete Recipe</a>
                </div>
                {/*End Card Block*/}
            </div>
            {/*End Collapsable*/}
        </div>
        {/*End Card*/}
    </div>

    );

}


export default RecipeCard;
```

## edit-recipe.js

```
import React from 'react';


const RecipeEditer = (props) => {

    var index = props.index;

    var cookBook = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cookBook"));
    var editMe = cookBook[props.forglory.currentRecipe];

    const UpdateRecipe = () => {

        var formData = $('#recipeEditer').serializeArray();


        var newRecipe = {};

            newRecipe.title         = formData[0]['value'];
            newRecipe.image         = formData[1]['value'];
            newRecipe.ingredients   = formData[2]['value'].split(',');
            newRecipe.steps         = formData[3]['value'].split(',');

        cookBook[index] = newRecipe; 

        localStorage.setItem("cookBook", JSON.stringify(cookBook));


    }


    return (

        <div className="modal fade" id="editRecipe" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editRecipeLabel" aria-hidden="false">
          <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div className="modal-content">
              <div className="modal-header">
              {/* Title */}
                <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
                    Edit Recipe
                </h5>
                <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="false">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="modal-body">
                <form id="recipeEditer" name="editRecipe">

                    <label htmlFor="name"><h4>Name</h4></label>
                    <input id="name" className="form-control" name="title" type="text" defaultValue={editMe.title} />

                    <label htmlFor="image"><h4>Image</h4></label>
                    <input id="image" className="form-control" name="image" type="text" defaultValue={editMe.image} />

                    <label htmlFor="ingredients"><h4>Ingredients</h4></label>
                    <textarea id="ingredients" className="form-control" name="ingredients" rows="4" cols="48" defaultValue={editMe.ingredients}></textarea>
                    <label htmlFor="steps"><h4>Steps</h4></label><br/>
                    <textarea id="steps" className="form-control" name="steps" cols="48" rows="4" defaultValue={editMe.steps} ></textarea>

                </form>
              </div>
              <div className="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                {/*Submit Button*/}
                <button onClick={UpdateRecipe} type="button" className="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Change Recipe</button>
                {/*Submit Button*/}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
}


export default RecipeEditer;
```

## thank you very much if you even glanced, if there is any more information that can help please don't hesitate to ask !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding `changeRecipe` to `this` in `recipe-book.js`, thus setting its context to `RecipeBook`.

Try changing

```
<RecipeCard index={index} key={index+1} recipe={recipe} changeRecipe={changeRecipe.bind(this)} />
```

to

```
<RecipeCard index={index} key={index+1} recipe={recipe} changeRecipe={changeRecipe} />
```

You may not even have to use bind in `app.js`, since `changeRecipe` is defined as an arrow function.

Comment: Weirdly enough it works either way as far as actually changing the recipe goes. I guess I fixed the editing the right one, however, right now when the modal opens it still has the information from the first recipe and doesn't change. (So I'd have to completely re-do the recipe every time) 

Here is an image if it's any visual help https://imgur.com/a/gh0av

Comment: well that wasn't too hard, seems I didn't need to post the question at all as I've already solved the data showing up issue. (Took a bit because jquery was giving me troubles so I just used vanilla JS). I added this to the 'change recipe' function

`document.getElementById('edit-name').value = this.state.recipes[arg].title;`
    ...  for each field.                                               Thank you for your help and I'll remember that I don't need to bind it if I use an arrow function !

Comment: Congrats on solving the problem. As next step in your learning curve, you should probably read up on Controlled components.

Comment: Thank you for all your help! You helped me focus on what the issue was and I'll be sure to check out Controlled components after my class :) I'm going to mark your answer as the correct one so that anyone who comes here sees it and all these comments.